# Does the left join order matter in linq query (EF Core 2)?

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core

I have **book** table which has a relationship with three tables **UserFavorites**, **UserRates**, **DiscountItems** and last one (**DiscountItems**) has a relationship with **Discounts** table so I want to load discount with book if it exist

When create linq left join query with this order **(join userfavoirtes then discountitems then discount then userate)** generated SQL code is fine as expected

But when change order like below **(join userfavoirtes then userate then discountitems then discount)** generated query only contain first two join only

```
 var books = (from b in result
                         join uf in UnitOfWork.Context.UserFavorites
                        on new { b.Id, RelatedType = RelatedTypeEnum.Book, UserId = userId }
                        equals new { Id = uf.RelatedId, uf.RelatedType, uf.UserId } into buf
                         from f in buf.DefaultIfEmpty()

                         join di in UnitOfWork.Context.DiscountItems
                             on b.Id equals di.BookId into bdi
                         from di in bdi.DefaultIfEmpty()

                         join d in UnitOfWork.Context.Discounts
                         on (di != null ? di.DiscountId : 0) equals d.Id into bd
                         from d in bd.DefaultIfEmpty()

                         join ur in UnitOfWork.Context.UserRates
                         on new { b.Id, UserId = userId }
                         equals new { Id = ur.BookId, UserId = ur.CreatedBy } into bur
                         from r in bur.DefaultIfEmpty()

                         select new BookViewModel
                         {
                             Id = b.Id,
                             Title = b.Title,
                             Price = b.Price,
                             BookImage = SetDefaultImageIfNoImage(b.BookImage),
                             IsFavorite = f != null ? f.IsFavorite : false,
                             Rate = bur.Any() ? Math.Round(bur.Average(a => a.Value), 1) : 0,
                             Discount = d
                         })
                       .OrderBy(a => a.CategoryId)
                    .ThenBy(a => a.Authors)
                    .Take(10).ToList();
```

this is generated sql query

```
  SELECT *FROM [Book] AS [a]
LEFT JOIN [UserFavorites] AS [uf] ON (([a].[Id] = [uf].[RelatedId]) AND (3 = [uf].[RelatedType])) AND [uf].[UserId] IS NULL
LEFT JOIN [DiscountItems] AS [di] ON [a].[Id] = [di].[BookId]
LEFT JOIN [Discounts] AS [d] ON CASE
    WHEN [di].[Id] IS NOT NULL
    THEN [di].[DiscountId] ELSE 0
END = [d].[Id]
LEFT JOIN [UserRates] AS [ur] ON ([a].[Id] = [ur].[BookId]) AND [ur].[CreatedBy] IS NULL
WHERE ((([a].[Active] = 1) AND ([a].[Id] <> 62)) AND ([a].[Status] = 1))
```

but when write join with this order

```
var books = (from b in result
                             join uf in UnitOfWork.Context.UserFavorites
                            on new { b.Id, RelatedType = RelatedTypeEnum.Book, UserId = userId }
                            equals new { Id = uf.RelatedId, uf.RelatedType, uf.UserId } into buf
                             from f in buf.DefaultIfEmpty()

                             join ur in UnitOfWork.Context.UserRates
                             on new { b.Id, UserId = userId }
                             equals new { Id = ur.BookId, UserId = ur.CreatedBy } into bur
                             from r in bur.DefaultIfEmpty()

                             join di in UnitOfWork.Context.DiscountItems
                                on b.Id equals di.BookId into bdi
                             from di in bdi.DefaultIfEmpty()

                             join d in UnitOfWork.Context.Discounts
                             on (di != null ? di.DiscountId : 0) equals d.Id into bd
                             from d in bd.DefaultIfEmpty()

                             select new BookViewModel
                             {
                                 Id = b.Id,
                                 Title = b.Title,
                                 Price = b.Price,
                                 BookImage = SetDefaultImageIfNoImage(b.BookImage),
                                 IsFavorite = f != null ? f.IsFavorite : false,
                                 Rate = bur.Any() ? Math.Round(bur.Average(a => a.Value), 1) : 0,
                                 Discount = d
                             })
                           .OrderBy(a => a.CategoryId)
                        .ThenBy(a => a.Authors)
                        .Take(10).ToList();
```

generated SQL query contains only the first two joins

```
SELECT *
FROM [Book] AS [a]
LEFT JOIN [UserFavorites] AS [uf] ON (([a].[Id] = [uf].[RelatedId]) AND (3 = [uf].[RelatedType])) AND [uf].[UserId] IS NULL
LEFT JOIN [UserRates] AS [ur] ON ([a].[Id] = [ur].[BookId]) AND [ur].[CreatedBy] IS NULL
WHERE ((([a].[Active] = 1) AND ([a].[Id] <> 62)))
```

Comment: What if `UserRates` is 3rd?

Comment: table - we have main table (book) and join with him many table (UserRates => book user rate it,UserFavorites,.....
-
finaly we create sql view wrapper all this logic and quuery with it